# Rails instance methods conditional depending on attributes being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null-object-pattern

I have a model that has several attributes that are optional when the model is being saved.

I have several instance methods that use these attributes and perform calculations but I would like to check first if they are not nil as I will get the dreaded `no method error nil nil class`

Apart from littering my code with `.present?` is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
Here is my code so far

```
def is_valid?
   (has_expired? === false and has_uses_remaining?) ? true : false
end

def has_expired?
   expiry_date.present? ? expiry_date.past? : false
end

def remaining_uses
  if number_of_uses.present?
    number_of_uses - uses_count
  end
end

def has_uses_remaining?
  number_of_uses.present? ? (remaining_uses > 0) : true
end
```

I feel like dropping in `.present?` to perform checks has a bad code smell, I have looked into the null object pattern but it doesnt seem to make sense here as the object is present but some of the attributes are `nil`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: @Jordan Just made some edits, hopefully it will be a bit more clear now

Comment: Under what circumstances would `number_or_uses` not be present?

Comment: @Jordan just added a comment below your answer explaining why number_of_uses sometimes is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that `number_of_uses` can be `nil`, which (as you've discovered) introduces a ton of complexity. Try to eliminate that issue first.

If for some reason you can't do that, each of your methods can be improved:

1. `condition ? true : false` is *always* a code smell. Boolean operators return boolean(ish) values, so let them do their jobs:

   ```
   def is_valid?
     !has_expired? && has_uses_remaining?
   end
   ```
2. Personally I think using Rails' [`Object#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) is usually a code smell, but here it's a pretty good fit:

   ```
   def has_expired?
     expiry_date.try(:past?)
   end
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```
   def has_expired?
     expiry_date.present? && expiry_date.past?
   end
   ```
3. This one can't be improved a whole lot, but personally I prefer an early `return` to a method wrapped in an `if` block:

   ```
   def remaining_uses
     return if number_of_uses.nil?
     number_of_uses - uses_count
   end
   ```

   You could also do `number_of_uses && number_of_uses - uses_count` (or even `number_of_uses.try(:-, uses_count)` but I think this is clearer.
4. It's a little weird that this method returns `true` if `number_of_uses` is `nil` bit since it does we can simplify it like so:

   ```
   def has_uses_remaining?
     remaining_uses.nil? || remaining_uses > 0
   end
   ```

   Note that I call `remaining_uses.nil?` instead of `number_of_uses.nil?`; there's no need to depend on both when we can get the same result from one.

### Further improvements

Upon further consideration I think you can make the intent of this code clearer by introducing another method: `has_unlimited_uses?`:

```
def has_unlimited_uses?
  number_of_uses.nil?
end

def is_valid?
  !has_expired? &&
    has_unlimited_uses? || has_uses_remaining?
end

def remaining_uses
  return if has_unlimited_uses?
  number_of_uses - uses_count
end

def has_uses_remaining?
  has_unlimited_uses? || remaining_uses > 0
end
```

This way there's never any ambiguity about what you're checking for.  This will make the code more readable for the next person who reads it (or you six months from now) and make tracking down bugs easier.

It still bothers me, though, that `remaining_uses` returns `nil`. It turns out that if instead we return `Float::INFINITY`, `has_uses_remaining?` turns into a simple comparison:

```
def remaining_uses
  return Float::INFINITY if has_unlimited_uses?
  number_of_uses - uses_count
end

def has_uses_remaining?
  remaining_uses > 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that amazingly in depth answer. Number of uses can be nil as a user can set that number. E.g this model is about discount codes and so a user can optionally set the attribute if they want to restrict uses if it's nil they can use it infinitely.

Comment: Upvoted for looking at the context, not just the code

Comment: In relation to point 4 the reason it can return nil is because by default if expiry_date is not set by the user and number_of_uses is not set by the user then is_valid? Will be true as the discount code will work. But any of those attributes are set I need to perform the methods to check if the discount code is still valid

Comment: @SamMason I've edited my answer to show some further improvements that could be made around the semantics of `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Short-circuiting usually works best in these situations.

Before:

```
if @attribute.present?
  @attribute.do_something
end
```

Short-circuiting:

```
@attribute && @attribute.do_something
```

With the short-circuiting approach, as soon as Ruby sees that the left side of the `&&` operator is `nil`, it will stop and not run the right side

I would also think hard about why a particular attribute should ever be allowed to be `nil` (as Jordan asked).  If you can think of a way to avoid this, that may be better.

Assuming that you do want `number_of_users` to be able to be `nil`, you could rewrite `has_uses_remaining?`like this:

```
def has_uses_remaining?
  !number_of_uses || remaining_uses > 0
end
```

-Side note: your first method can be simplified to this:

```
def is_valid?
   !has_expired? && has_uses_remaining?
end
```